# jQuery Dual Conditional Statement - Scroll Height OR Width Do This

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work out how to have a function that changes some css when either the screen scrolls to a certain point, OR the browser window shrinks to a certain size.

Individually I have each working, but one overrides the other when I follow one with the other.

Here's what I'm working with atm:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height > 300){
    $('.navbar-default .nav li a').css("color","#f6f6f6");
    }
    else{
    $('.navbar-default .nav li a').css("color","#4B00B3");
    }
});

 $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width < 768) {
    $('.navbar-default .nav li a').css("color","#f6f6f6");
    }
    else{
    $('.navbar-default .nav li a').css("color","#4B00B3");
    }
});
```

So I want to simply have the navbar font be a grey(#f6f6f6) at 300px scroll AND when the screen is beyond 768px wide.  Otherwise be dark purple(#4B00B3).

I've tried combining these but I'm not sure how to combine the .resize and .scrollTop events properly with the || conditional statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine them into a single function, then pass that function to both the resize and the scroll events.

```
var navbarDefault = $('.navbar-default .nav li a');

$(window).resize(toggleColor).scroll(toggleColor);

function toggleColor(){
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = $(window).width();

    if(width < 768 || height > 300) {
        navbarDefault.css("color","#f6f6f6");
    }
    else {
        navbarDefault.css("color","#4B00B3");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Post your relevant HTML, CSS, and JS code for us to look at.

Comment: There we go, I had to move the top variable call under the height and width variable calls.
One last problem is when the browser is small the starting font color is wrong.  So I need to add in a (document).ready as well.  Can I just append that to the 2 window events?

Comment: Nvm on the document ready.  I sorted it out with @media queries.
Thanks mucho for your help Bobby!
P.S. I edited your code moving the variable to where it worked for me.